# Присвоение класса к UL по клику (не получается разобраться)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброе время суток!

Есть сайт, не могу реализовать присвоение класса по клику способом который нашел на сайте. Не работает меню на сенсорных устройствах.

`.click`– класс объекта, по которому кликают.
`.drop`– класс объекта, в который нужно добавить классы
`.hmenu visible`– класс, который добавляется или удаляется по клику.

Все назначил, но при клике на объект `li` с классом click ничего не происходит, класс не назначается объекту `ul` вложенному в `li`

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста! 
Спасибо!

```js
$(function() {
  $('click').click(function() {
    $('dropmenu').toggleClass('hmenu visible');
  });
});
```

```html
<li class="item-106 deeper parent click">
  <a href="#">Регистрация</a>
  <ul class="dropmenu">
    <li class="item-113 click">
      <a href="/registratsiya/ooo">ООО</a></li>
    <li class="item-114 click"><a href="/registratsiya/ip">ИП</a></li>
    <li class="item-115 click"><a href="/registratsiya/pao-zao">ПАО НАО</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Селектор класса должен начинаться с точки

Comment: Пробовал и с точки, то же самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как указали в комментарии, селектор класса должен начинаться с точки. Попробуйте исправленный вариант.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('.dropmenu').toggleClass('hmenu visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.dropmenu {
  display: none;
}
.deeper .visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item-106 deeper parent click">
  <a href="#">Регистрация</a>
  <ul class="dropmenu">
    <li class="item-113 click">
      <a href="/registratsiya/ooo">ООО</a></li>
    <li class="item-114 click"><a href="/registratsiya/ip">ИП</a></li>
    <li class="item-115 click"><a href="/registratsiya/pao-zao">ПАО НАО</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Делал так, к сожалению почему то такая конструкция и скрипт не работают. Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Возможно, дело не в скрипте а в стилях. Например, если посмотреть инспектором разметку, то возможно в вашем случае класс таки добавляется к элементу. Но стили написаны так, что главнее оказывается тот, что прячет дочернии элементы.

Comment: Да, вы были почти правы, правда у меня слайдер на главной вступал в конфликт с скриптом, поэтому не работало. noConflict спасло.